Initialising Multivariate linear regression with the maximum likelihood method
I am attempting to use maximum likelihood estimation to fit a multivariate linear regression problem. I have 5 predictor variables and a similar number of response variables. I am using a correlation-variance parameterisation of the covariance matrix. Is there a ‘best’ method to initialise the optimisation? I have guessed at using multiple linear regressions for the coefficients and the correlations and variances resulting from those linear regressions.
Edit: on reflection I’m probably seeking a method of moments estimator.

linear regression most of the cases have a closed form solution, which is independent to the conditioning of the problem

If your problem is least squares, then the MLE differs from the OLS solution only in an adjustment of the error variance estimate.  If you problem is something else, such as a GLM, then OLS often is a good way to initialize the parameters anyway.  // By "multivariate" do you mean, as is conventional, that the response is vector-valued; or perhaps did you really intend to write "multiple" (more than one explanatory variable)?

Both are vector valued, although my question is motivated by the response variables being vector valued.

Is it not the case that the coefficients from a multivariate linear regression fit with either OLS or MLE are equal to those resulting from fitting the regression models separately? If the issue is computing the joint covariance matrix of the coefficients, M-estimation or simultaneous equation models can be used.

@Noah Concerning your initial question, the answer is yes when the response components are not correlated (which is the implicit assumption used by lm in R, for instance), but otherwise, the results can (and usually do) differ from the componentwise regressions.

The response variables are quite correlated in some cases. I think the first two comments answer the question I probably should have asked before starting. Is the any additional advantage to MLE over OLS when your response variables are correlated?
